# Can't save variables inside of chrome storage sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to return a boolean value within a function about whether a user is blocked or not but I can't as I'm trying to save a variable inside of the chrome sync callback function but it doesn't save it, and even though my local storage has a variable inside that list it shows it's empty as the variable didn't copy the values of the data.blocked_users.

```
//Return true if the user by url is blocked, false otherwise
function isblocked(blocked_id) {

    var blocked_users = [];//The list of blocked users

    chrome.storage.sync.get(['blocked_users'], function(data){
            blocked_users = data.blocked_users;
    });

    console.log("U" + blocked_users + "U");

    //Goes through blocked users
    for(var current_blocked of blocked_users) {
        console.log("B"+current_blocked+"B");
        if(current_blocked == blocked_id) return true;//If the user is blocked 
    }

    console.log(blocked_users+"QQ");

    return false;   


}
```

It says "UU" and "QQ" despite my actual list being not empty.
I've tried many things but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `chrome.storage.sync.get` does not mean sync code. It means that this data will be sync in chrome by google account. AFAICS, there has no way to do that get data in storage by sync, it must use the callback.

The code like:

```
function getIsBlocked(blocked_id,callback) {

    var blocked_users = [];//The list of blocked users

    chrome.storage.sync.get(['blocked_users'], function(data){
        blocked_users = data.blocked_users;

        console.log("U" + blocked_users + "U");

        //Goes through blocked users
        for(var current_blocked of blocked_users) {
            console.log("B"+current_blocked+"B");
            if(current_blocked == blocked_id){
                callback(true);//If the user is blocked 
                return;
            }
        }

        console.log(blocked_users+"QQ");

        callback(false);

    });

}


getIsBlocked(blocked_id,function(isblocked){
    //do sth
});
```